# Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'FC'. in '@types/reactour'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working in a react application.
I had my **package.json** file as follows.

```
`{
  ...
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-backgrounds": "^3.4.8",
    "@storybook/react": "^4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "@types/d3": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/debug": "^0.0.30",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.1.9",
    "@types/jest": "^23.1.4",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.0.38",
    "@types/react-color": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/react-copy-to-clipboard": "^4.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.4",
    "@types/react-intl": "^2.3.16",
    "@types/react-mentions": "2.4.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/react-router": "^4.0.22",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/react-select": "^1.2.6",
    "@types/react-show-more": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/redux-form": "^7.3.1",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/storybook__addon-backgrounds": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/storybook__react": "^3.0.8",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "connected-react-router": "^4.4.1",
    "cosed": "^1.1.8",
    "d3": "^5.7.0",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "debug": "^3.1.0",
    "duplicate-package-checker-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "emoji-mart": "^2.6.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "gen-tester": "^3.1.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "immer": "^1.3.1",
    "jest": "^23.3.0",
    "jest-environment-enzyme": "^6.0.2",
    "jest-enzyme": "^6.0.2",
    "jest-styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^7.2.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "prettier": "^1.13.7",
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-color": "^2.17.3",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
    "react-cosed": "^1.0.9",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.8.0",
    "react-mentions": "^2.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-select": "^1.2.1",
    "react-show-more": "^2.0.0",
    "reactour": "^1.8.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-cosed": "^1.0.1",
    "redux-form": "^7.4.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^3.1.6",
    "ts-jest": "^23.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.13.0",
    "tslint-no-circular-imports": "^0.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.7",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.15.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,tsx}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash.debounce": "^4.0.4",
    "@types/reactour": "^1.13.1",
    "firebase-tools": "^6.1.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8"
  }
}
```

`

I tried to add intro tour for my application with `reactour`.
And when I added the package 'reactour' in my application it asks for `@types/reactour` and I added that too.
But still facing some package depending issues.

I added these..

```
`"dependencies": {
    ...
    ...
    "@types/reactour": "^1.13.0",
    "reactour": "^1.8.5",
    ...
    ...
}`
```

The errors are in console...

```
> ✖ ｢atl｣: Checking finished with 13 errors [at-loader]
> ./node_modules/@types/react-mentions/index.d.ts:38:24 
>     TS2314: Generic type 'UIEvent<T>' requires 1 type argument(s). 
> 
> [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-mentions/index.d.ts:45:22 
>     TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'RefObject'. 
> 
> [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-mentions/index.d.ts:45:61 
>     TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'RefObject'. 
> 
> [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/reactour/index.d.ts:276:43 
>     TS2314: Generic type 'ReactElement<P>' requires 1 type argument(s). 
> 
> [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/reactour/index.d.ts:278:43 
>     TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ComponentPropsWithRef'. 
> 
> [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/reactour/index.d.ts:281:27 
>     TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'FC'. 
> 
> [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/reactour/index.d.ts:287:43 
>     TS2314: Generic type 'ReactElement<P>' requires 1 type argument(s). 
> 
> [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/reactour/index.d.ts:289:46 
>     TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ComponentPropsWithRef'. 
> 
> [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/reactour/index.d.ts:290:30 
>     TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'FC'. 
> 
> [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/reactour/index.d.ts:292:41 
>     TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ComponentPropsWithRef'. 
> 
> [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/reactour/index.d.ts:299:25 
>     TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'FC'. 
> 
> [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/reactour/index.d.ts:301:37 
>     TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ComponentPropsWithRef'. 
> 
> [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/reactour/index.d.ts:302:32 
>     TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'FC'.
```

Please suggest some solution ...
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It worked for me.
Deleted the `yarn.lock` file and removed `node_modules` after updating the `@types/react`.

And did yarn install.

Answer (score 22):

Update the @types/react to the **latest version** or a specific version to match your react and react-dom packages.

`npm i @types/react@latest --save-dev`

or

`yarn add @types/react --dev`

You do not need to replace your node_modules or your lock file.

Answer (score 17):

This error can also happen if you forget to name your file's extension as `.tsx` and leave it as `.ts`

Answer (score 8):

If you're coming from an IDE such as Visual Studio and it's throwing this error (compared to the OP which was from the command line), restarting the IDE often solves this error.

Answer (score 7):

Update your `@types/react` to the latest version (which is [16.9.9 atm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react)).

You might need to run `npm i @types/react --save-dev`, but manually replacing the version should work too.

Comment: I tried  `npm i @types/react --save-dev`, Still the error remains.

Comment: What happens if you manually replace the version of @types/react with 16.9.9?

Comment: Strange, at least the first three errors should've disappeared with that.

Comment: Try updating the types for react-dom and react-redux to the latest versions as well.